# Phone Application For .Net

Tags: .net, mobile-phones

As a .net developer mainly c#, I want to know what would be the best approach for me to develop Phone application that runs on major phones.

Just to let you know Iphone is out of the question because of the costs that are involved, not ready to buy Mac book.

I want something I can develop within Windows operating system, Android could have been the best option but it does not integrated well with .net.

Any idea  please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .NET you can target Windows Mobile which is soon to be replaced by Windows Phone 7. So has a short shelf life.

The SDK for Windows Phone 7 is [available now](http://developer.windowsphone.com/Default.aspx), but the phones won't hit the stores until October. You could get a head start on that platform though.

Also the MonoTouch team have started work on [MonoDroid](http://monotouch.net/Roadmap) which will allow you to develop .NET applications for Android phones. It isn't available yet, but will hopefully be out around August.

So, basically, right now, Java will give you far more options for mobile development; allowing you to cover the Symbian, Blackberry and Android systems. But, by the end of the year there will be a lot more opportunities for .NET developers in this sector.

Comment: Martin thanks for your help. Looks like I will give it try with windows 7 if I can't find any other option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricting yourself to .Net, then you dont have many options. .Net CF runs only on Windows Mobile based phones. But If you just want to develop for free, and on windows, You can go for Symbian S60 using C or Python; or J2ME.

And I believe Android has a perfectly fine SDK, Which needs not be integrated with .Net FW

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop in .NET, you have [androidmono](http://github.com/koush/androidmono) for android phones.
Here is a blog with info regarding android mono: [My Brain Hurts: Android Mono](http://www.koushikdutta.com/search/label/Android%20Mono)

.NET for iPhone you have [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation), you still have to develop on a Mac though.

Comment: You may want to be careful developing in MonoTouch since Apple changed the Development Agreement. The MonoTouch folks claim that it fulfills the "spirit" of the agreement (http://monotouch.net/), but it is still a gray area in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Jens, like i said I don't have any plan to buy Mac at the moment. I want to see if one can develop something without mac. Just want to use available resources I have at the moment. Hopefully I will find something thanks for your help

Comment: @Martin, good to know, I have no plan my self to develop for iPhone and if I´m going to do any development for Android it will probably be in Java.

Comment: @Terry, you could develop android apps with androidmono and MonoDevelop(http://monodevelop.com/), works on Windows, Linux & Mac.